# Partitions created in spark are mutable or immutable in nature?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to know about the partitions which have been created during spark job execution, are mutable or immutable in nature?

Answer (score 1):

Spark RDDs or Datasets are by definition immutable, thus the partitions are also immutable.